# How to solve the error while installing packages in Atom

Tags: python, npm, atom-editor

whenever i tried to install a package in atom a get an error as mention bellow

**

> Installing “platformio-ide-terminal@2.10.1” failed.Hide output…
> npm ERR! code Z_BUF_ERROR
> npm ERR! errno -5
> npm ERR! zlib: unexpected end of file
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\A.atom.apm_logs\2021-02-07T09_09_47_927Z-debug.log
> **

please help me to solve this problem.

[This is the visuals of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7BmB.png)

Answer (score 1):

1. Close all atom windows.
2. Rename ~/.atom directory in your /username folder to something else or just delete it.
3. Restart Atom.
4. Now try to install package.